# Attempting to print yields an index error, but the code runs fine without?

Tags: python

Attempting to add the rows of a 2D list together and then add the summed rows together for a grand total. However, Every tome I try to print I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list.py", line 17, in 
    Row_Value = Row_Value + int(numbers[I][J])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

No errors whatsoever without the call to print, which i need to happen in order to satisfy my class

```
# Get our list from the command line arguments
import sys
numbers= sys.argv[1:]

# Convert the command line arguments into 2d list
for i in range(0,len(numbers)): 
  numbers[i]= numbers[i].split(',')

# Write your code below
Row_Value = 0
Row_Memory = 0
Number_of_Rows = len(numbers)
Number_of_Columns = len(numbers[1])
for I in range(0, Number_of_Rows):
  for J in range(0, Number_of_Columns):
    Row_Value = Row_Value + int(numbers[I][J])
  print (Row_Value)
  Row_Memory = Row_Memory + Row_Value
  Row_Value = 0
print (Row_Memory)
```

Additionally, adding the line 
    print ('hello World')
Prints hello world and the final value of Row_Memory Fine Without any error. as soon as I delete the other print though, the error is back.

Also, Without the final call to print we get

Program Failed for Input: 1,1,-2 -1,-2,-3 1,1,1
Expected Output: 0
-6
3
-3
Your Program Output: 0
-6
3

Any Help is appreciated =/

Comment: Are you passing your inputs in correctly? Your code will work fine if the input is well-formed, but if even one row is missing a number you will see the error you are getting. Maybe have a check before you run your logic to make sure all the rows are of the same size?

Comment: range(0, n) is a bit redundant. range(n) would work since by default range(n) returns 0 to n-1.

Comment: Show a reproducible run, including the command line you used

Comment: thanks for the tips.I simplified my code as per Tom Johnson's suggestion, and the inputs are all of the same same row size.

Comment: Your code runs without error and outputs the expected input with the provided inputs for me.